# ajax based online php tester

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, testing

I have to check alot of code chunks of php so I am looking for online php testing tool which works using ajax.

I know there are several tools online for php testing but they are not using ajax, refresh page each time, some has captcha and that's all time taking, not easy when doing testing again and again.

Is there any online php testing tool using AJAX to show output ?

Comment: What specifically do you want to test? Syntax or execution?

Comment: When you say 'testing', what do you mean? What kind of AJAX features are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @richsage, @Or-w: I want to check output of my code, only output is my concern but I don't like page refresh each time so looking for tool which use AJAX to show output so I can go faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html file using jquery:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<label for="filename">PHP filename</label>
<input type="text" name="filename" id="filename"/>
<textarea id="output" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea>
<button id="test">test</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
  var output = $('#output');
  $.get('test.php', 'filenam=' + $('#filename').val(), function(data, s, xhr) {
    output.val(data);
  });
});
</script>
...
```

test.php file

```
exec("php -l " . $_GET['filename'], $output);
echo $output;
```

it will run cli version of php with lint option on filename passed through AJAX from input field and print the output to textarea.

Comment: It should be noted that the poster will need to include jquery in their project, as I don't think they ever mentioned it.